# How to know if user in session has changed?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, model-view-controller, logging

I'm making a page for submitting some info about user and after that data is inserted in database.

How can I know if current user has changed?

I'm using CodeIgniter and I can get users id but it's the always active one. How do I know if session has changed after page load?
Right now other user could log in another tab and submit on first tab would post session id from latest user.

Comment: Use a CSRF token. In addition, it will protect your form from other risks (specifically: cross site request forgery).

Comment: session will store in browser not in tab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use tokens therefore sessions will be stored in the users browser not in tabs. Check the PHP documentation or YouTube videos they have good tutorials on how to do this effectively.